# Catching magento product status change and validate against product data

Tags: magento

I am trying to implement functionality in a magento project to validate each product before changing it's status to enabled. I have a custom attribute (internal status) which contains a bool value and I don't want the admin user to be able to enable the product if this value is "false".

How can I catch this event so I can display an error message and not allow the status change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution in the end, so i'm posting in case anybody else needs it.

First step was to add an observer to the event **catalog_product_save_before** in the /code/local/Custom/Catalog/etc/config.xml

```
    <events>

        <catalog_product_save_before>
            <observers>
                <custom_catalog_observer>
                    <class>Custom_Catalog_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>validateStatusChange</method>
                </custom_catalog_observer>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_before>
    </events>
```

Then i created Observer.php file with the method validateStatusChange:

```
<?php

class Custom_Catalog_Model_Observer {

public function validateStatusChange(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    Mage::log('Status change id ' . $product->getId() . " NEW " . $product->getData('status') . " OLD " . $product->getOrigData('status') . " SAP " . $product->getData('sap_disabled'));
    if ($product->getData('status') == 1 && $product->getData('sap_disabled') == 1) {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Product status can not be changed to Enabled while SAP Disabled is active!');
        $product->setData('status', 2);
        $product->save();
    }
    return true;
}


}

?>
```

The custom module needs to be registered in /etc/modules by creating a file Custom_Catalog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Custom_Catalog>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
       <depends>
        <Mage_Catalog />
       </depends>
    </Custom_Catalog>
   </modules>
</config>
```